# Routes in WCF - Can it be like MVC?

Tags: wcf

**Disclaimer**: Yes I know WCF isn't the Web API or MVC.  However I'm trying to figure out a hack to do sort of what MVC does with routing so that I may be able to keep the same method names in my .svc contract behind the scenes when I wire up different requests with different sets of querystring params.

So I have this dumb WCF service and I want to have an overload of Get methods in here.  But I can't, WCF bitches about it when I try to make a call to this service.

I have 2 methods named "Get" that I'm trying to essentially overload but differentiate by querystring.  Notice the two below have different sets of querystrings in the uri so my intent is not having to have all these different Get, GetbySomething, GetBySomething2.  It'd be nice to just stick with the name Get() on all mymethods and just overload them / differentiate them so that the request coming in can wire up to maybe the querystring differentiation sort of like MVC does:

```
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?securityToken={securityToken}&brokerId={brokerId}&orderStatus={orderStatus}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sortBy={sortBy}&purchaseOrderNumber={purchaseOrderNumber}")]
        public OrderResponse Get(string securityToken, string brokerId, string orderStatus, string pageNumber, string pageSize, string sortBy, string purchaseOrderNumber)

   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?securityToken={securityToken}&brokerId={brokerId}&purchaseOrderNumber={purchaseOrderNumber}&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sortBy={sortBy}")]
        public OrderResponse Get(string securityToken, string brokerId, int purchaseOrderNumber, string startDate, string endDate, string pageNumber, string pageSize, string sortBy)
```

Error in response coming from WCF: "Cannot have two operations in the same contract with the same name, methods Get and Get in type OrderService violate this rule. You can change the name of one of the operations by changing the method name or by using the Name property of OperationContractAttribute. "

ok whatever fine.  So can I somehow use a route table in my global.asax to essentially do what MVC can do?

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Inventory", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InventoryService)));
```

MVC allows me to map but takes into account the querystring as part of the matching:

Just an example, I could take into account querystrings ?someParam={someValue}

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}?someParam={someValue}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

yes I also know in MVC you can overload your methods to differentiate them via parameters in the controller and as you can see here my WCF contract methods for Get() do have different set of params so one would think WCF would let you differentiate the same method name by params but it doesn't.

You can overload the functions to accept different parameters
Because in WCF the way you specify the querystring match part is via attribute:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?securityToken={securityToken}&brokerId={brokerId}&purchaseOrderNumber={purchaseOrderNumber}&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sortBy={sortBy}]
```

so is there a way to use my R`outeTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("V1/Inventory", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InventoryService)));` that I have in my global.ascx to somehow all me to make Get method names unique and overload them by differentiating them by querystring?

Because right now to fix this I'd have to make one of my Get method names something else which is IMO stupid and unclean.  I'd have to do something like GetByDateRange.  So I'd have to do something like:

```
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?securityToken={securityToken}&brokerId={brokerId}&orderStatus={orderStatus}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sortBy={sortBy}&purchaseOrderNumber={purchaseOrderNumber}")]
        public OrderResponse Get(string securityToken, string brokerId, string orderStatus, string pageNumber, string pageSize, string sortBy, string purchaseOrderNumber)

   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?securityToken={securityToken}&brokerId={brokerId}&purchaseOrderNumber={purchaseOrderNumber}&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sortBy={sortBy}")]
        public OrderResponse GetByDateRange(string securityToken, string brokerId, int purchaseOrderNumber, string startDate, string endDate, string pageNumber, string pageSize, string sortBy)
```

This puts me back into RPC style method names behind my web service handling and I hate that.  We are using WCF restfully as well so I'd like to keep this clean by just having a bunch of overloaded Put() methods, Get(), etc.

Comment: I think you should simply rename one of your Get methods but let the WCF differentiate on UriTemplate.

Comment: I know I can do that, but in the backend it's nice to have consecutive Get() overloads to keep it simple and clean.  That's my whole itch here.